# linker error undefined symbol _log10f

Tags: c, windows, linker, turbo-c

I am using `log10f` function of `math.h` header file and I need to calculate   log value in float that's why I use the above function

I am just posting the sample code instead of the actual code due to confidential information

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main(){

    printf(" --->>> %f \n", log10f(4) - log10f(3));
}
```

Some how I am able to run that code in linux using gcc compiler with following command and it compiled properly and running properly

```
gcc Demo.c -lm -o Demo

./Demo
```

But I have to run the project on the windows too and I am using window 7 and turbo c but using tc my program compiled properly but at run time it showing me a `LINKER ERROR UNDEFINED SYMBOL _LOG10F`

Anyone have any Idea that how can I resolve this issue on Tc at windows.
Suggestions are most welcome thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your code doesn't use `log10f` (well, before the edit). And about TurboC, don't tag "gcc" and throw the program away now. As you're using gcc on Linux, why not on Windows too (mingw-w64)?

Comment: by mistake I post the wrong code So I edit my question .... I tag gcc just because of the reason that I am able to run this code in gcc but not in tc

Comment: That's not a good reason to tag GCC. You tag the technologies you're asking about.

Comment: Again, throw away TurboC (which is about 20 years old), and just use GCC/MinGW, the everything works fine.

Comment: @deviantfan actually client have tc so I have to manage it for him I suggest him to check on gcc but he denied that's why I post here

Comment: Turbo C will not work on Windows 7. I believe it is only capable of generating 16 bit binaries and I believe Microsoft stopped supporting them long time ago. Why would you want a compiler which forces you to deliver a 16 bit emulator with every program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log10f` was added to the C language 16 years ago. You are using a a compiler which is 25 years old, so it won't work.

A work-around might be to use `log10` instead, which was available in the C90 standard. It uses `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: its working fine and running on tc and gcc both thanks a lot